# jquery slider with additional buttons

Tags: jquery, button, slider

EDIT: posted on jsfiddle to make it easier to help out: http://jsfiddle.net/GXf45/

I've been able to create a slide show (thru the use of tutorials and stack overflow) and now I'm working on adding some functionality; a button for each slide in the show.

the previous and next buttons work perfectly (especially on the first and last slides) but I'm having issues with the intermediate buttons.  Later I imagine the jquery adding buttons based on the number of slides.

The code below is just one of the revisions i'm working on.  I'm thinking there are LOTS of opportunities to improve what i have.  Let me know  where my errors are and what you may do to clean this up.  Thanks.

The html has some ruby at the beginning which populates a div based on some partials.

html:

```
<div class='slider'>
    <ul>
    <% Dir["app/views/main/show/*"].each do |file| %>
      <li><%= render :file => Rails.root.join(file).to_s %></li>
    <% end %>
    </ul>

</div>
    <div id='slider-nav'>
    <button data-dir='prev'>Prvious</button>
    <button data-dir='next'>Next</button>
    <button data-dir='1'>1</button>
    <button data-dir='2'>2</button>
    <button data-dir='3'>3</button>
    <button data-dir='4'>4</button>
</div>
```

js:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    var sliderUL = $('div.slider').css('overflow', 'hidden').children('ul'),
    imgs = $('.showScene'),
    imgWidth = $('.showScene').width(),
    imgsLen = imgs.length,
    current = 1,
    totalImgsWidth = imgsLen * imgWidth;


    $('#slider-nav').show().find('button').on('click', function(){
        var direction = $(this).data('dir'),
        loc = imgWidth;

        //update current value
        //(direction == 'next' ) ? ++current : --current;

        if (direction == 'next')
            {
                current += 1; //2
            } 
        else if (direction == 'prev') 
            {
                current -= 1;//0
            }
        else
            {
                current = direction;    
            }

        //if first image
        if ( current == 0 ) {
            current = imgsLen;
            loc = totalImgsWidth - imgWidth;
            direction ='next';
        } else if ( current - 1 == imgsLen){
            current = 1;
            loc = 0;
        }

        transition(sliderUL, loc, direction);

    }); 

    function transition( container, loc, direction ){
        var unit; //-= or +=

        if ( direction && loc !== 0) {
            unit = ( direction == 'next') ? '-=' : '+=';
        }

        container.animate({
            'margin-left': unit ? (unit + loc) : loc
        });

    };


});
```

css:

```
*{margin:0px;padding: 0px;}
.showScene{
    width: 800px;
    height: 300px;

}

#slider-nav{
    margin-top: 1em;
    display: none;

}
#slider-nav button{
    padding: 1em;
    margin-right: 1em;
    border-radius: 10px;
    cursor: pointer;
}
.slider{
    width: 800px;
    height: 300px;
    border: 2px solid grey;
    overflow: scroll;

}
.slider ul {
    width: 10000px;
    list-style: none;


}
.slider ul li{
    float:left;
    list-style-type: none;

}
```

Comment: Could you maybe get the code running in http://jsfiddle.net/ and upload a link?

Comment: Do you have some specific problem or error you are looking for help on?  A request to generally "help improve my code" is not really expected format for questions here.

Comment: help get intermediate buttons working.  jsfiddle link added

Comment: Could you perhaps come up with a smaller example?  This is a lot of code to go through.  If you can create just one button, and that doesn't work, it'll be easier to see than if we have to sift through this much code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're missing the logic that works out the `loc` and `direction` parameters for the numbered buttons. Here is the main snippet, note I refactored your code a little to reuse the sliding logic. You just needed to work out how much you need to slide by from your current position, and which direction to slide.

```
var num = parseInt(direction);
if (num !== current) {
    loc = imgWidth*(num -current);
    if (loc < 0) {
        direction = 'prev';
        loc = -loc;
    } else {
        direction = 'next';
    }
    current = num;
    doSlide(direction, loc);
}
```

Try [this](http://jsfiddle.net/GXf45/2/) fiddle.

Comment: That looks like it!  Thank you! I couldn't get the logic right; you made that look really simple!